# Store a constant reference in an S4 object - R

Tags: r, object, reference, r-s4

I'm programming a neuroscientific software with R. I principally operate with two S4 classes, `eeg` and `analysis`. Every instance of the second is the result of calling a certain function in an instance of the first. In other words, every `analysis` instance comes from an `eeg` instance (it is a particular statistical analysis of that EEG data).

*Some*, but not all the methods in the `analysis` class, need to extract information or manipulate the original EEG data. So far, I've solved this by making the `analysis` object such that it contains a slot with a copy of the `eeg` instance it originates from. Every `analysis` object is readily created with a duplicate of the original EEG in this slot. The methods that require the original EEG data can access it via this slot.

The problem is that EEG data is very large. Every time I perform the statistical `analysis` over an `eeg`, this very same eeg object is duplicated in the aforementioned slot of the `analysis` instance. This results in a massive memory overload and causes issues, sometimes crushing RStudio even. It is not economical to store a copy of the original EEG in each analysis only because *some* of the methods in the analysis class require it.

Is there a way to store, in an S4 class, a constant reference to an object without duplicating it? I would like each `analysis` instance to "know", or to be able to reference, the `eeg` instance it originates from, without the need of duplicating that instance in any way.

Comment: R already employs copy-on-modify semantics. Slot assignment should not result in a copy. Are you sure that you are not somehow modifying the `eeg` instance as part of your analysis, which could result in a copy? Can we maybe see a minimal reproducible example, using `trace` to look for copies?

Comment: As a slight frame challenge, why not have a single class that has two slots: (1) a single `eeg` object and (2) a `list` where each element of the list is an `analysis` object? That way you only need one copy of the `eeg`, no matter how many analyses you want to do on it. That said, this is not the only way and it is certainly possible to use `get` or similar to manage references across objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Reference Class` (nickname `RC`) for your `eeg` class

```
EEG_Class <- setRefClass("EEG_Class", fields = c("vec1", "vec2"))
setClass("Analysis_Class",
    slots = list(
        eeg_obj = "EEG_Class",
        res1 = "numeric",
        res2 = "numeric",
        res3 = "numeric",
        res4 = "array"
    )
)
```

Let's test drive:

```
eeg_obj1 <- EEG_Class$new(vec1 = runif(10000000), vec2 = sample(letters, 10000000, TRUE))
lobstr::mem_used() # 216.35 MB

# Toy function to analyze an eeg object and return an Analysis_Class object
ff <- function(eeg_input) {
    new(
        "Analysis_Class",
        eeg_obj = eeg_input,
        res1 = mean(eeg_input$vec1),
        res2 = sum(eeg_input$vec1),
        res3 = length(eeg_input$vec1),
        res4 = tapply(eeg_input$vec2, eeg_input$vec2, length)
    )
}
m1 <- ff(eeg_obj1)
lobstr::mem_used() # 216.61 MB

m3 <- m2 <- m1
lobstr::mem_used() # 216.66 MB

m2@eeg_obj$vec1 <- m2@eeg_obj$vec1 + 1
m2@eeg_obj$vec2 <- toupper(m2@eeg_obj$vec2)
lobstr::mem_used() # 216.66 MB
identical(m1@eeg_obj, m2@eeg_obj) # TRUE
identical(m2@eeg_obj, m3@eeg_obj) # TRUE
m2 <- ff(m2@eeg_obj)
lobstr::mem_used() # 216.73 MB
```

If you check the `res*` slots in `m1` vs `m2`, you are going to see differences despite the same `eeg_obj` slot. This is due to the reference semantics of `eeg_obj` slot, so you should be careful with this approach as it is quite different from the functional model of S4.